# PHP insert index as value in array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

How can I add to a multidimensional array also the index number of the current added item?

```
$data_array[] = array('data_array_index' => *the index number of the this array on $data_array*, 'stuff' => 'stuff', etc.)
```

So when I:

```
print_r($data_array);

Array(
  [0] => Array(
            data_array_index => 0
            stuff => stuff
         )
  [25] => Array(
            data_array_index => 25
            stuff => stuff
         )
  etc.
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

Should this work?

```
$data_array[] = array('data_array_index' => end($data_array)+1, 'stuff' => 'stuff', etc.)
```

Comment: you can't "add", you have to rebuild the array. `array(0=>array('data_array_index'=>0,etc...))`

Comment: I'm inside a foreach loop, who rebuilds the array at each loop with the added data. BTW, this is not answering my question....

Comment: Just a question, why do you need the key in `data_array_index` inside the array if you'll probably not be able to access it directly since you won't have the `$data_array` key to it?

Comment: I need later to access all data associated with key 'data_array_index' in all multidimensional arrays inside $data_array

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$array = [
   0 => [ "data_array_index" => 0, "stuff" => "stuff" ],
   25 => [ "data_array_index" => 25, "stuff" => "stuff" ]
];

$array[] = array('data_array_index' => 0, 'stuff' => 'stuff')

end($array);
$last_id = key($array);

$array[$last_id]['data_array_index'] = $last_id;
```

I don't know why you want `data_array_index` in the array because if you put it in a `foreach` loop you can get the key without needing the variable.

Example:

```
foreach($key => $data) {
        ^^^^ The same as `data_array_index`
}
```

Comment: Inefficent for very large arrays

Comment: @Perocat, For as far as i know this is the fastest method.

Comment: @Perocat, it is O(1), and can hardly be improved. Could you elaborate in which way it is inefficient ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this array:

```
$data_array = [
   0 => [ "data_array_index" => 0, "stuff" => "stuff" ],
   25 => [ "data_array_index" => 25, "stuff" => "stuff" ]
];
```

Now to set a key (note the `$data_array[100]`):

```
$data_array[100] = [ "data_array_index" => 100, "stuff" => "stuff" ];
```

Comment: I guess he wanted some kind of "automatism", as he doesn't know the key 100 in advance.

Comment: @Jan Then I miss understood.

Comment: @Jan yes it's like you describled, it should be "automatic"

Comment: I guess there are only two possible solutions for an index: either the end (this can be calculated by `count()`) or if you splice the array. But in both ways you will end up knowing the index in advance, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
$arr=array(12=>array("stuff"=>"stuff1"),15=>array("stuff"=>"stuff2"));

foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
$arr[$key]['data_array_index']=$key;    
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Inefficent for very large arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk`

```
array_walk($data_array,function($value,$key)use($new_array) {
    $value['data_array_index'] = $key;
    $new_array[$key]=$value;
});
```

working demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p937-7cue

Answer (score 0):

For my solution see the code below. Beware that this is a very rudimentary function now. It does not provide any fail safe or fallback. If you delete a key it will to fill the space etc.

```php
<?php

// data array
$data_array = [];

// additional info for the array
$info_a = "Lorem Ipsum";
$info_b = "Lorem Ipsum";

// call function
addElement($data_array, $info_a);
addElement($data_array, $info_b);

// display output
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_array);
echo '</pre>';

function addElement(&$array, $info)
{
    // add info to the array
    $array[] = [
        'stuff'=>$info
    ];

    // get the key of the current array
    end($array);
    $key = key($array);

    // add this information to the array
    $array[$key]['data_array_index'] = $key;
}
?>
```

Output would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stuff] => Lorem Ipsum
            [data_array_index] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [stuff] => Lorem Ipsum
            [data_array_index] => 1
        )

)
```